# Flask WTForms custom validator is always showing 'Username or password is incorrect'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

i am trying to set custom validator for login form but it always show that 'username and password are incorrect' even when i put the valid ones. Any suggestions?
here is my code:

```
def login_check(form,field):
    user_email = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
    if user_email is None:
        raise ValidationError('Username or password is incorrect')
    elif not check_password_hash(field.data, user_email.password):
        raise ValidationError('Username or password is incorrect')

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):

    email = StringField('Email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[InputRequired(),login_check])
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i replaced werkzeug.security with passlib.hash pbkdf2_sha256 and now it is working, i don't know why is that

code

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

def login_check(form,field):
user_email = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
if user_email is None:
    raise ValidationError('Username or password is incorrect')
elif not pbkdf2_sha256.verify(field.data, user_email.password):
    raise ValidationError('Username or password is incorrect')
```

route

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST','GET'])
def register():
    reg_form = RegistrationForm()
    if reg_form.validate_on_submit():
        password = reg_form.password.data
        hased_pass = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(password)
        user = User(name=reg_form.name.data, lastname=reg_form.lastname.data,
                email=reg_form.email.data, password=hased_pass)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        login_user(user)
        flash(f'Welcome {user.name}, Your account have been created')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```